# Different line heights using inline-block on IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, inline, css

I am creating a webpage to work in IE7. I want to vertically center a span (which may be several lines long) in a speech bubble. I have achieved this in modern browsers by setting the `line-height` property of the span's parent to the height of the span's parent itself. The span is then given the `display` property `inline-block`, its `line-height` property is set to something which corresponds to its font size and its `vertical-align` property is set to `middle`. However, when I try to view it in IE7, the line height of the span's text seems not to be that of the span and instead is that of the span's parent. It is as if the span did not have the inline-block display property as this is what you would expect if it was inline. As the span element is inline by default, you would expect the inline-block property to work in IE7 but it does not. I have tried applying things like `zoom: 1;` and the ['cross-browser inline block' suggested by css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/) but none of this works. I am seriously considering using a table but that is really not something I want to resort to.

You can take a look at the issue at http://jsfiddle.net/sAuhsoj/bWdwE/ (you may want to view the fullscreen version http://jsfiddle.net/sAuhsoj/bWdwE/embedded/result/ using [browserlab.adobe.com](http://browserlab.adobe.com) to see how it looks in IE7)

Comment: Have you tried display:block ?

Comment: Yes, it does not achieve the vertically centered effect. The effect it does create would be acceptable since it only needs to be shown on IE7 but it is not possible to only apply display: block in IE7 without something like <!--[if IE 6]><![endif]--> (which I want to avoid). This is because if I put display: block above display: inline-block then IE7 tries to display the span as inline-block. If I put display: block after display: inline-block, all browsers will display it as a block element.

Comment: I can't remember if 6 or 7 is the last IE that ignores the !important attribute, but its worth giving it a shot:  `display: inline-block !important; display: block`

Comment: I changed your `rem` units to `em` units and it works in IE.  Perhaps IE doesn't understand the `rem` unit?  I wouldn't be surprised.  Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/bWdwE/2/

Comment: @Axel bingo. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this particular case is the use of the `rem` unit on the line-height attributes.

By simply changing `rem` to `em`, it solves the issue in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/bWdwE/2/

Answer (score 2):

To target IE7 with a CSS hack, you can add this display rule:

```
*display : block;
```

a so written **property* is processed by IE7 and lower only.

---

May i suggest you to use [conditional comments on `<html>` tag](http://kaioa.com/node/107)?
Personally, i use:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>  <html class="ie ielt8 ielt9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>  <html class="ie ie8 ielt9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>  <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]> <html class="ie10"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--> <html> <![endif]-->
```

Then i can target any IE browser this way:

```
.ielt8 .anyClass {
    /* any rule here will effect ie7-6 only */
}
.ie8 .anyClass {
    /* any rule here will effect ie8 only */
}
.ielt9 .anyClass {
    /* any rule here will effect ie6-7-8 only */
}
.ie9 .anyClass {
    /* any rule here will effect ie9 only */
}
.ie10 .anyClass {
    /* ie10, for future reference */
}
.ie .anyClass {
    /* any ie but 10 */
}
```

That's really easier and you don't have to use hacks, which is better for validation and will exclude any future possible interference.

In your case, you could set up a completely new style for IE7, like

```
.userQuote .quoteText {
    display: block;
    line-height: a pixel value;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Axel solved the problem but I still really appreciate all the effort you took to right this clever, informative answer.

Comment: Np. i also noticed the `rem`, but as he alredy pointed it out i removed it from my answer ;)